# Why the content inside view is not displaying in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

I would like to know why the contents inside the view are not displaying on storyboard.

Please look at the image below for your reference[image: ViewController]

Comment: Did you `Command + delete` ?

Comment: Are you asking me to do that? or asking whether i did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have designed in a size class other than wAny/hAny and you switch to wAny/hAny your controls will be grayed out. To enable them in other size classes you have to add the size class in the property inspector.

Select the grayed out element in the document outline (its possible even it is grayed out) and add the size class in the property inspector:

[image]